# I am using the chemfig package, but for a formula it doesn’t not draw the last oxygen atom

Tags: chemfig

Consider:

[image]

```
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-(-N(=[:90]O)(=[:210]O))=)}}{1,3-dimethyl-5-nitrouracil}
    \arrow{->[\ce{Fe}, \ce{HCl}]}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-=(-NH_2)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O))}}{5-Amino-1,3-Dimethylurcil}
    \schemestop
```

Where the red circle is, it is supposed to be an oxygen atom. -(=O)

Comment: Is there a reason for mirroring the molecule on a vertical axis? (The N-CH3-group is located at the right side of the ring in the reactant, while it is located on the left side of the ring in the product.)

Comment: So you have plenty of choices now :) // Tried to find out, why your code fails to display the oxygen. But may be that became less relevant now ;-)

Comment: After the last hexagon bond is made, the "chemfig" program no longer writes anything. Put whatever you want in the last link (=O) as the first object in the ring.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{
  \chemfig{
    *6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-(-N(=[:90]O)(=[:210]O))=)
  }
}{1,3-dimethyl-5-nitrouracil}
\arrow{->[\ce{Fe}, \ce{HCl}]}
\chemname{
  \chemfig{
    *6((=O)-N(-CH_3)-=(-NH_2)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-)
  }
}{5-Amino-1,3-Dimethylurcil}    
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a little systematic trial and error, this is, what works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-(-N(=[:90]O)(=[:210]O))=)}}{1,3-dimethyl-5-nitrouracil}
    \arrow{->[{Fe}, {HCl}]}
\chemname{\chemfig{[:60]N*6(-=(-NH_2)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-)([:270]-CH_3)}}{5-Amino-1,3-Dimethylurcil}    
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

1 ) Looks like at least the second diagram must be rotated. (Diagrams seem to start at 07:30 o'clock, not at 06:00.)

2 ) The `\arrow` in your version gave an error, so I modified it until it passed.

Result:

[image: modified second molecule]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative, that makes sure, the uracil rings are oriented in the same direction in reactant and product. I also made sure, the reaction arrow is slightly longer to account for the width of the reagents text on top of the arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-(-N(=[:90]O)(=[:210]O))=)}}
           {1,3-dimethyl-5-nitrouracil}
  \arrow{->[\ce{Fe}, \ce{HCl}]}[0,1.5]
  \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-(-NH_2)=)}}
           {5-amino-1,3-dimethyluracil}     
\schemestop

\end{document}
```